# Twinkling of the notification luminodiode indicator. Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to make luminodiode twinkled when the notification arrives in my program.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity()).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher). setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Content"); 
    Notification notification = builder.build(); 
notification.ledARGB = Color.RED; 
notification.ledOffMS = 0; 
notification.ledOnMS = 0; 
notification.flags = notification.flags|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
notificationManager.notify(101, notification);
```

Now it always lits in red color, not twinkling.  How to make it twinkling? I tried to change values in this lines

```
    notification.ledOffMS = 0; 
notification.ledOnMS = 0;
```

But it didn't help. What's wrong?